# when I try to set a static page that I have built as the homepage it gives an error saying too many redirects

Tags: wordpress

when I choose the permalink structure to PLAIN everything works fine,
but when i select post name or ant other structure the homepage stops working and gives an error saying too many redirects but everything else works fine

Comment: Can you provide some more clues? I would open my dev tools in Chrome or Firefox and check the network tab to see what the redirects were.

Comment: Also, this question doesn't comply with SO rules because it's not about programming. SO recommends putting this type of question here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com and you're likely to get better responses there.

Comment: sorry about that, I will post it there